# How would one turn numbers (amount) in dictionary to characters?

Tags: python

I've got the code here;

```
dictionary_x = {
"option_1": 12,
"option_2": 0,
"option_3": 5,
"option_4": 4
}

def show_results(results):
print("option_1  :", results["option_1"])
print("option_2  :", results["option_2"])
print("option_3  :", results["option_3"])
print("option_4  :", results["option_4"])
```

currently it prints out like this;

```
option_1  : 12
option_2  : 0
option_3  : 5
option_4  : 4
```

what should I do, to be able to print it out like this, almost like it's tallied.

```
option_1  : ############
option_2  : 
option_3  : #####
option_4  : ####
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something along the following lines, using string formatting and being more DRY with a loop over the dict items:

```
def show_results(results):
    for k, v in results.items():
        print(f"{k} : {v * '#'}")

>>> show_results(dictionary_x)
option_1 : ############
option_2 : 
option_3 : #####
option_4 : ####
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dictionnary comprehensions you could try this one line solution: (should work as is)

```py
>>> {k: v*'#' for k, v in dictionary_x.items()}
{'option_1': '############',
 'option_2': '',
 'option_3': '#####',
 'option_4': '####'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with simple;

```
def show_results(results):
print("option_1  :", "#" * (results["option_1"]))
print("option_2  :", "#" * (results["option_2"]))
print("option_3  :", "#" * (results["option_3"]))
print("option_4  :", "#" * (results["option_4"]))
```

Comment: I would suggest not going with this but rather with one of the other answers. Why repeat the same code 4 times?..

Comment: Yes, the answer by @scwobaseggl is a lot better and is duly noted for further reference, but I decided to go with simple repeat for simple code for this one.